# How can I download installer for Second Life Firestorm Update 6.6.3.67470 with Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: updates, firefox, downloads, 22.10, konqueror

How can I download the installer for Firestorm Update 6.6.3.67470 from firestormviewer.org with Ubuntu 22.10?

- Konqueror 21.12.3 & Firefox 108.0.1 (64) cannot. No file downloads.
- Firestorm was working perfectly until I upgraded Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10.
- After the update, Firestorm, when ran, reported a change in the graphics environment in a dialog window that closed on its own.
- Next, Firestorm mini-cored and asked if I wanted to send the core in for analysis.
- I did this twice.
- The firestorm site recommended a reinstall of Firestorm Update 6.6.3.67470 after deleting the Firestorm directory and its preferences dot directory contents, clearing the browser cache, and downloading the Firestorm Update 6.6.3.67470 for a fresh install.
- Neither web browser could download this.
- No error messages, no partial download. Nothing.